# Displaying the first value of the array in datasets.label Chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm facing an issue with my code.
Here is my code:

```
                    var jahr = [];
                    var objekteName = [];
                    var jahrData = [];


                    //selected years
                    var postedData = {};
                    postedData.years = $('#mf123_select_jahr').val();
                    //


                    //selected objekte
                    postedData.objekteLFN = $('#mf123_objekte').val();
                    //

                    
                    console.log($('#mf123_objekte').val());



                    $.ajax({
                        url: "data/json.dashboard.php?call=chart3"
                        , dataType: 'json'
                        , type: 'POST'
                        , data: postedData
                        , success: function (dataGraph3) {


                            for (var i in dataGraph3) {
                                var labelNames = Object.keys(dataGraph3[i]);
                                var labelValues = Object.values(dataGraph3[i]);

                            }

                            console.log(labelNames);
                            

                            for (var i in labelNames) {
                                for (var j in postedData.years) {
                                    if (labelNames[i] == postedData.years[j]) {
                                        jahr.push(labelNames[i]);
                                        jahrData.push(labelValues[i]);
                                    } 
                                }
                            }


                            for (var i in labelValues) {
                                for (var k in postedData.objekteLFN) {
                                    if (labelValues[i] == postedData.objekteLFN[k]) {
                                        objekteName.push(labelValues[i]);
                                    }
                                }
                            }




                            console.log(objekteName);



                            //data
                            var myChart2Data = {
                                labels: jahr
                                , datasets: [

                                    {
                                        yAxisID: 'leftYaxis'
                                        , label: objekteName
                                        , borderWidth: 1
                                        , data: jahrData
                                        , borderColor: "#de425b"
                                        , backgroundColor: "#de425b"
                                        , order: 3
                                        , borderWidth: 3
                                        , fill: false

                                    }
                                ]
                            };

   

var config2 = {
                                type: 'line'
                                , data: myChart2Data
                                , options: {
                                    plugins: {
                                        datalabels: {
                                            display: false
                                        }
                                    }
                                    , maintainAspectRatio: true
                                    , responsive: true

                               }

                              }
```

I'm trying to push an array in datasets.label but when I refresh the page it shows only the first value of the array. I want to have dynamic label NOT labels and I have tried so many times without result.
I can't understand the way it works on datasets.label. Considering the other variables they work fine!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post the whole code? it seems the half of it.

Comment: yes of course!!

Comment: is `objekteName` defined outside of the `ajax` call?

Comment: Yes.. I defined it outside of the Ajax call. The other charts that I have complete, I also defined them the variables outside of the Ajax calls

Comment: if i get it correctly, `objekteName: []` holds a single value instead of multiple, right? You mention that it only displays the `first` value.

Comment: Yes as usual holds a single value. But I want to pass a dynamic value such as an array because I have many datasets to display without hardcoding. Is there any option for this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225396/discussion-between-sonkatamas-and-nick-zagkanas).

Answer (score 0):

After adding elements to `data.labels` and values to `data.datasets.data`, you need to invoke `chart.update()`.

> Please consult [Adding or Removing Data](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html#adding-or-removing-data) from Chart.js documentation.

Comment: could you give me an example of that? Im new in javascript so I hope an example will be helpful :)

Comment: @Nick Zagkanas: Please take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61576710/2358409